# Attendance Checking using firebase angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem using firebase and angular for ionic. What i want to achieve is when users click list of dates then example 8 sept then user can see all attendace status of 8 sept.

[image: List of dates]

after user click 8 sept. It show the list of user data and status of attendance in 8 sept.

[image: After user click one of the dates it show the attendance list and their status]

this is my firebase database

[image: this is my firebase database]

So far i can display the list for every dates and user data. But the problem is my query display the status for all dates(8&9 Sept). How i can display the status for selected dates only?

this is my code that i have been working on.

**Controller.js**

```
childUsers.orderByValue().on('value', function(snapshot){
    $timeout(function(){

        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();

        $scope.users =snapshotVal;
        console.log($scope.users);

      });
    });
```

**Template**

```
 <div ng-repeat= "item in users">
            <div class="list card" style="padding:1%;">
                <div class="col-50" style="float:left;">

                <h5>{{item.displayName}} - {{item.handphone}}</h5>
                <h5>{{item.email}}</h5>  
                </div>
                <div class="col-33" style="float:right; position: relative; ">

                    <div ng-if="item.status = 'true'">
                        <div class="ion-checkmark" style="display: flex;  vertical-align: middle;"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using nested snapshot here is my code

**CONTROLLER**

```
  var rootRef = new Firebase('https://example-app.firebaseio.com/');
    var childUsers = rootRef.child('users');
    var childDate = rootRef.child('tanggal');
    var rekapId = $stateParams.rekapId;
    console.log(rekapId);      

  childDate.child(rekapId).child('tanggalBaca').once('value',function(snap){

        $timeout(function() {
             var snapshot= snap.val();
            $scope.tanggal = snapshot;       
            console.log($scope.tanggal);
            myAfterFunction();
         });
    })

    function myAfterFunction(){

   var dates = $scope.tanggal;
   console.log(dates);
   var rekapUsers = childUsers.on('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var key = childSnapshot.key();
            console.log(key);
            var childStatus = childUsers.child(key+'/status/'+dates);
            childStatus.on('value',function(grandsnap){
                var snapval =grandsnap.val();
                $scope.statusbaca = snapval;
                $scope.key = key;
                console.log($scope.statusbaca);
                console.log($scope.key);
              })

        })
        var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();          
        $scope.users =snapshotVal;
        console.log($scope.users);
    })     

    }
```